# What fraction of a liquid rocket launching from Mars to return to Earth would be fuel?

Tags: mars, rockets, fuel, payload, mass

I've tried to get my head around this and have decided that, for the moment, I don't want to learn to solve logarithmic equations. Too much else going on. 
I was reading [Mars Direct](http://www.marssociety.org/home/about/mars-direct) and got the impression from the very abbreviated info there that about 80% would be fuel. That surprised me because the gravity is so much weaker and the air is so thin on Mars. Is that right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a Map to the Solar System. It details, roughly how much $\Delta v$ you need to get from one place to the next.

[image: Subway Map]

You can take the rocket equation to quickly calculate your Fuel fraction for any given $\Delta v$. We take the basic form ($m_0$ starting mass; $m_1$ final mass; $v_\text{e}$ effective propellant exit velocity)
$$
\Delta v = v_\text{e} \ln \frac {m_0} {m_1}
$$
And introduce the fuel fraction $M_f=\frac{m_0-m_1}{m_0}$
$$
M_f = 1-\frac {m_1} {m_0}=1-e^{-\frac{\Delta V}{ v_\text{e}}}
$$

(I was too tired to derive that by myself, so I took it out of Wikipedia. Not that it's hard to do...)

Mars Direct wants to use in-situ-produced methane and oxygen for the return. The theoretical ISP of this fuel combination is 368.9s. That equals an effective exhaust velocity of $368.9\text{s}\cdot \text{g}=3618\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$.

To return to earth we need at least an intercept. Dennis Tito wants to return from mars and plunge right into the earth's atmosphere (yes, I know it's more complicated), so if you fly that way, you only need to intercept earth, not go into an orbit before you land.

That way your $\Delta v$ would be $(3800+1400+1060)\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}=6260\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$.

Pluck that into the equation above and you get:

$$
M_f = 1-e^{-\frac{6260\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}}{3618\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}}}=0.82
$$

Since this a very ideal calculation, with a flatrate model for Mars air drag and gravity losses, perfect engine, etc, 80% is a bit optimistic. But then again, maybe the maker of that solar system map took a worse constellation for reference, than Mars Direct did. I don't know.

Source for the ISP: Modern Engineering for Design of Liquid-Propellant Rocket Engines (AKA The Huzel)

Comment: Man, that delta v map is excellent. I didn't see that one when i searched for them.

Comment: The derivation you provide is actually very helpful. I'm sure it is very low level math for an engineer, but it makes my life a lot easier. I'm capable of plugging numbers into that one. Sure would be nice if all the relevant numbers were available in one place though... haven't found such a place.

Comment: Wait, what value did you use for g? When i plug in 3.7 m/s as the value for gravity on Mars, the result is 1707 m/s.

Comment: The $g$ has nothing to do with Mars.  It is simply a conversion factor between English units (pounds-force thrust per [pounds-mass propellant per second]) and Metric units (Newtons per [kg/s] == m/s) for Isp.

Comment: The equivalent free-space $\Delta V$ for a Mars ascent vehicle needs to be more like 4200 m/s (instead of 3800 m/s), in order to account for gravity loss and drag.

Comment: Just always put in 9.81 m/s^2 as g. As Mark correctly stated, it's just a unit thing.

Comment: I believe there is a lower energy option for flights leaving Earth--using the moon for a gravity assist.

Comment: Such maps make simplifying assumptions, such as maybe circular orbits and some average planetary conjunction. In reality one would use eccentric orbits and aerobreaking and whatever conjunction available and get other results. The real delta-v is unique for every mission.

Comment: I did factor in aerobraking. Moon assists give you nothing. Mars' moons are too small and I already assume that you can kill the whole $v_\infty$ by aerobraking. Sure there are assumptions to a subway map like that (as I pointed out in my answer). Some return maneuvers use Venus for a fly-by. That may work. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: No, actually Venus flybys won't help either, if you go that way.

Comment: 27000 m/s to land on Venus. Is that a typo, or why is it so?

Comment: No, it's not a typo. If you land, you will not need any impulse, because you can use the Atmosphere. It's so dense that in 1978 one of the pioneer Pioneer 13 probes survived an impact although it was not designed to and had had no parachute. If you land, you just need a tiny parachute. But the enormous atmosphere makes launching from Venus' surface almost impossible.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi So it is launching from, not landing on? I suppose that landing from low orbit requires trivial delta-v.

Comment: Yes, just launching. Not only does the drag slow you down, but chemical engines are much less efficient in a high-pressure environment. The only reasonable way to launch from Venus in my view is to use a balloon to float to the upper atmosphere, and then start an engine there.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi You did consider even the rocket efficiency in atmospheres? That's amazing! But now to my next perhaps equally naive question: Why are the inner Jovian moons more difficult to intercept from Jupiter orbit, than his outer moons? Shouldn't the higher variation in speed of the inner moons, relative to that of the Sun or Earth, instead make them more available because a probe could match their trajectories more easily with optimal timing? Couldn't one put an orbiter around Io directly, without first putting it around Jupiter?

Comment: To clarify: I did not make that map. The original creator is written in the top left. Comments on stackexchange are not meant for further questions. Please open a new question. Short answer: Yes the inner Moons are harder to reach, but you can use swing-by maneuvers to get there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17104/discussion-between-localfluff-and-rikki-tikki-tavi).